# LWJGL Textures in VBO

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

Ok, well I made a simple 3D cube using VBO, and I wanted to load textures onto it. Only problem is that the textures are all messed up, here is my code:

```
public void create() {
    setup();
    render();
}

private void makeCube(float x, float y, float z) {
    int cube = glGenBuffers();
    int texture = glGenBuffers();
    FloatBuffer cubeBuffer;
    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

    float highX = x + tileSize;
    float highY = y + tileSize;
    float highZ = z + tileSize;

    float[] textureData = new float[]{
        0,0,
        1,0,
        1,1,
        0,1
    };

    textureBuffer = asFloatBuffer(textureData);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    float[] cubeData = new float[]{
        /*Front Face*/
        x, y, z,
        highX, y, z,
        highX, highY, z,
        x, highY, z,
        /*Back Face*/
        x, y, highZ,
        highX, y, highZ,
        highX, highY, highZ,
        x, highY, highZ,
        /*Left Face*/
        x, y, z,
        x, y, highZ,
        x, highY, highZ,
        x, highY, z,
        /*Right Face*/
        highX, y, z,
        highX, y, highZ,
        highX, highY, highZ,
        highX, highY, z,
        /*Bottom Face*/
        x, y, z,
        x, y, highZ,
        highX, y, highZ,
        highX, y, z,
        /*Top Face*/
        x, highY, z,
        x, highY, highZ,
        highX, highY, highZ,
        highX, highY, z,};

    cubeBuffer = asFloatBuffer(cubeData);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);

}

private void renderCube() {
    textures.get(0).bind();
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 22);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

private void render() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        camera();

        renderCube();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(30);
    }

    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}

private void setup() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(frameWidth, frameHeight));
        Display.setTitle("3D Project");
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(vSync);
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Camera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), zNear, zFar);
    //glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glLoadIdentity();

    loadTextures();

    makeCube(0, 0, -1);

}
```

[image: VBO Textures]
The only thing I think is wrong with this is my texture coordinate array, if so, can anyone give me a correct order?

Yes I flip my buffers, and yes my images are powers of 2.

Comment: The answer you seek is in your implementation of `renderCube (...)`. You are using the same memory pointer for your vertex positions as you are for your texture coordinates.

Comment: But I do have to ask: why is the usage flag for your texture coordinates data different from the vertex position data? It looks like both sets of vertex data are static.

Comment: Well I plan on having a map of cubes (Minecraft style) and from my understanding, to modify the float data for each tile in the map, I should be using Dynamic drawing.

Comment: No, your tiles should be static. Generally speaking, barely anything ever happens to the tiles in the Minecraft world, so a static rendering system is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `renderCube (...)` is faulty:

```
private void renderCube() {
  textures.get(0).bind();
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

  /* These two pointers reference the same memory! */
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
  glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

  glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 22);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

What you need to do is bind the VBO for your vertex position immediately before calling       `glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)` and the VBO for your texture coordinates immediately before calling `glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)`.

These functions establish pointers to memory relative to the address space defined by whatever VBO is bound at the time you call them (or actual system memory pointers if you are not using VBOs).

```
/* Setup Position Pointer */
glBindBuffer    (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

/* Setup Texture Coordinate Pointer */
glBindBuffer      (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
glTexCoordPointer (2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```