# Multiple Cubes in one VBO

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

So, I've figured out how to accomplish this, sort of. My array is seemingly messed up. The problem is hard to explain, so Ill provide some pictures and code.

EDIT: The problem was the for-loops and the x1, y1, z1 variables being controlled by floats

```
public void create() {
    setup();
    render();
}

private void makeCube() {
    texture = glGenBuffers();
    cube = glGenBuffers();

    FloatBuffer cubeBuffer;
    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;

    ArrayList<Float> cubeList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> textureList = new ArrayList<>();

    float[] cubeFloat;
    float[] textureFloat;

    for (float x1 = 0; x1 < tileSize * width; x1 += tileSize) {
        for (float y1 = 0; y1 < tileSize * height; y1 += tileSize) {
            for (float z1 = -tileSize * depth; z1 < 0; z1 += tileSize) {
                float highX = x1 + tileSize;
                float highY = y1 + tileSize;
                float highZ = z1 + tileSize;

                float[] cubeData = new float[]{
                    /*Front Face*/
                    x1, y1, z1,
                    highX, y1, z1,
                    highX, highY, z1,
                    x1, highY, z1,
                    /*Back Face*/
                    x1, y1, highZ,
                    highX, y1, highZ,
                    highX, highY, highZ,
                    x1, highY, highZ,
                    /*Left Face*/
                    x1, y1, z1,
                    x1, y1, highZ,
                    x1, highY, highZ,
                    x1, highY, z1,
                    /*Right Face*/
                    highX, y1, z1,
                    highX, y1, highZ,
                    highX, highY, highZ,
                    highX, highY, z1,
                    /*Bottom Face*/
                    x1, y1, z1,
                    x1, y1, highZ,
                    highX, y1, highZ,
                    highX, y1, z1,
                    /*Top Face*/
                    x1, highY, z1,
                    x1, highY, highZ,
                    highX, highY, highZ,
                    highX, highY, z1};

                for (float f : cubeData) {
                    cubeList.add(f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cubeFloat = compileFloat(cubeList);

    for (int i = 0; i < (width * height * depth); i++) {
        float[] textureData = new float[]{
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0,
            1, 1,
            0, 1};

        for (Float f : textureData) {
            textureList.add(f);
        }
    }

    textureFloat = compileFloat(textureList);

    textureBuffer = asFloatBuffer(textureFloat);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    cubeBuffer = asFloatBuffer(cubeFloat);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

private float[] compileFloat(ArrayList<Float> list) {
    float[] f = new float[list.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        f[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    return f;
}

private void renderCube() {
    textures.get(0).bind();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24 * (width * height * depth));

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

private void render() {
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        camera();

        renderCube();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(30);
    }

    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}

private void setup() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(frameWidth, frameHeight));
        Display.setTitle("3D Project");
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(vSync);
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Camera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(fov, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), zNear, zFar);
    //glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glLoadIdentity();

    loadTextures();

    makeCube();

}
```

Making a 3x3x1 array yields this result:

[image: 3x3x1]

Though making a 2x2x1 array works perfectly fine.
[image: 2x2x1]

So this is what I think is going wrong, I have no idea how to fix it. (This was supposed to be 5x5x1.
[image: Problem]

Comment: First of all, if a 2x2x1 array is perfectly fine, then you should probably include a screenshot of that for reference. Otherwise, you really have not explained what is wrong in the diagram you did include. Second, the [last question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979673/lwjgl-textures-in-vbo) (which is related to this one) appears to be resolved, but you have not accepted the answer... you should either accept that answer and ***then*** ask your new question or edit that question to include this new information and delete this one.

Comment: Sorry, I have accepted that answer and will upload a screenshot of the 2x2x1 array.

Comment: It is very unusual to see a loop controlled by floating-point variables like this. If width or height are also floating-point, then really weird things can happen depending on their value. In any event, you will notice that the number of cubes is correct to form a square: 3**2 = 9, 5**2 = 25. But I am guessing you want these to be square, so the number of cubes in each column is 1 too many (for odd dimensions). Honestly, the first thing I would do is get rid of this freaky floating-point loop control logic.

Comment: Well they are floats because my tileSize is 0.1f. But I can certainly make the changes.

Wow, Thanks. Out of everything in the world, I never would have guessed it was the floats. Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would multiply everything by 10 then and divide by 10 in the body of your loop (integer multiplication and division). You should be aware that using floating-point, **0.1** cannot be represented precisely (at any precision).

Comment: I just turned everything into an int, and made the adjustments to compensate for the x10 tileSize. It worked though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for explaining the values used for `tileSize`. The value **0.1** cannot be represented in floating-point at any precision, it degenerates into a repeating fraction in base-2, much like everyone is familiar with 1/3 doing in base-10. Now, if you continue to add this number which is not exactly **0.1** to something, eventually the result will be appreciably different from what you would expect.

In general, it is best to avoid floating-point expressions for loop control. You may think that because the compiler happily accepts a floating-point constant such as **0.1** that all is well and that it can accurately represent that number, but if you do not understand the mechanics of floating-point math then weird things like this can happen.

In case you were curious, a more detailed explanation of the issue I mentioned can be found [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/).